# Python built-in list: remove one item

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [(32,(4,5)),(55,(5,6))]
```

Given a tuple (4,5), so I want to remove the first tuple in lst. How to do that?

Sorry, this wasn't clear, what I mean is remove the list item by the second item in each list item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lst2 = [(x, y) for (x, y) in lst if y != (4, 5)]
```

Removes ALL (4, 5) tuples, not just the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the list:

```
lst = filter(lambda x, y: y != (4,5), lst)
```

Comment: How about if (5,6) was given?

Comment: @user469652 What do you mean, given?

Comment: @user469652 Oh ok, I see your revised question

Comment: @user469652 Modified answer to use filter

Answer (score 1):

This removes the first list entry whose 2nd component matches, but **don't** use this to remove more than one.  To do more than one use a list comp as others have suggested or iterate over a copy of the list (for eaxmple: `for n in L[:]`).  Modifying a list that you are iterating has unexpected results.

```
>>> def remove(L,t):
...   for n in L:
...     if n[1]==t:
...       L.remove(n)
...       break
...
>>> L=[(1,(2,3)),(4,(5,6)),(7,(2,3))]
>>> remove(L,(2,3))
>>> L
[(4, (5, 6)), (7, (2, 3))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `lst2 = [(a,) for (a,b) in lst]' ?

That will result in`[(32,),(55,)]`